# how to use page-break-after:always inside bootstrap row?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am having a bootstrap row and contains set of div inside that row like this.

```css
@media print {
  p { page-break-after : always }
}
```

```html
<div class = "row">
  <div> data1 </div>
  <p> break page here </p>
  <div> data2 </div>
 <div>
```

the problem here is page break is not working inside the bootstrap row. anyone help me on this or suggest someother work around to do this.

Answer (score 0):

*you could use `inside()` element by **Css**,*

*for example:*

```
@media print {
  pre, blockquote {page-break-inside: avoid;}
}
```